# mysql lookup table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, inner-join, lookup, multiple-columns

#### Lookup table - unique row identity

The other lookup tables just do not make sense as from what I have seen giving a row an ID then putting that id in another table which also has a id then adding these id's to some more tables which may reference them and still creating a lookup tables with more id's (this is how all the examples I can find seem) What I have done is this :

```
product_item - table
------------------------------------------
id | title   | supplier   | price 
1  | title11 | suuplier1  | price1
```

etc.
it then goes on to include more items (sure you get it)

```
product_feature - table
--------------------------
id | title    | iskeyfeature 
1  | feature1 | true




feature_desc - table
-----------------------------
id | title | desc
1  | desc1 | text description





 product_lookup - table
    item_id | feature_id | feature_desc
    1       | 1          | 1
    1       | 2          | 2
    1       | 3          | 3
    1       |64          | 15
```

(as these only need to be referenced in the lookup the id's can be multiples per item or multiple items per feature)

What I want to do **without adding item_id to every feature row or description row** is retrieve only the columns from the multiple tables where their id is referenced in the same row of the lookup table. I want to know if it is possible to select all the referenced columns from the lookup row if I only know the item_id eg. `Item_id = 1` return all rows where `item_id = 1` with the columns referenced in the same row. Every item can have multiple features and also every feature could be attached to multiple items , this will not matter if I can just get the pattern right in how to construct this query from a single known value.

Any assistance or just some direction will be greatly appreciated. I'm using phpmyadmin, and sure this will be easier with some php voodoo I am learning mysql from tutorials ect and would like to know how to do it with sql directly.

Comment: I think you've normalized too deep on the feature. I would keep the feature_desc in the product_feature table. That makes your lookup table simpler. You don't have multiple descriptions for the same feature, right.

Comment: No I do not have multiple descriptions. Why I have normalized it so far down is for the single reason that I do not want it in my feature table when there is no description for the feature same with why the feature table, I want to keep things modular so if a certain item is not available this will not have empty values in my table and will only represent 0 in my lookup table. Then I can call only items and descriptions or I can build a full set, it will also mean I can have different items that may not have anything but a title in one table and then just add a category to the lookup table

Comment: If I can get this right, the flexibility of the database will be extremely useful will it not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a NULL value in a column is not the major concern that would lead to this design - it's the problem with *adding* new attribute columns in the future, at which MySQL is disgracefully bad.

If you want to make a query that returns everything about an item in one row, you need to LEFT OUTER JOIN back to the product_lookup table for each feature_id.  This is about every 10th mysql question on Stack Overflow, so you should be able to find tons of examples.

Comment: I did that thank you, why I did not consider the joins before was A. I've been working with the mysql for 3days now and just could grasp what joins do from the documentation ect. B. Most examples consist of a ID represented in another table and in the lookup which confused me.

Comment: So here is what I did ...SELECT * FROM product_lookup LEFT JOIN product_item.id ON product_item.id = product_lookup.item_id LEFT JOIN product_feature.id ON product_feature.id = product_lookup.feature_id LEFT JOIN product_desc ON product_desc.id = product_lookup.desc_id WHERE product_lookup.item_id = 1; On my real table however I have 6 JOINS and use the WHERE clause to limit results quite effectively. Left joins is better because inner joins I row had a null value the entire row would not be returned. Thank you all for your help.